# SQL Server : IF EXIST update or insert between similar database tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I would like to use a simple code to update or insert a record beetween two similar databases.

In **A** database there is a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].A.[tblDuyurular]
(
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [SiteID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Dil] [varchar](7) NULL,
        [DuyuruBaslik] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
        [DuyuruIcerik] [varchar](max) NOT NULL
)
```

In **B** database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].B.[TBLDuyurular]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [fakulteID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DuyuruBaslik] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [DuyuruIcerik] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [dil] [varchar](7) NULL
)
```

Matched columns are:

```
ID = ID,
SiteID = fakulteID,
Dil = dil,
DuyuruBaslik = DuyuruBaslik,
DuyuruIcerik = DuyuruIcerik,
```

I want to check dbo.B.TBLDuyurular records. If records exist in dbo.A.tblDuyurular then UPDATE dbo.A.tblDuyurular with dbo.B.TBLDuyurular's results. If records not exist in dbo.A.tblDuyurular, INSERT dbo.B.TBLDuyurular's results to dbo.A.tblDuyurular. Table columns are minimized. There are too many columns in these tables.

What is the best way for this situation?

Help please. Thanks.

Comment: Use Merge Statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try MERGE;

```
MERGE [dbo].A.[tblDuyuyular] AS TARGET
USING [dbo].B.[tblDuyuyular] AS SOURCE
ON TARGET.ID = SOURCE.ID 
AND TARGET.SiteID  = SOURCE.fakulteID 
AND TARGET.Dil  = SOURCE.dil
AND TARGET.DuyuruBaslik  = SOURCE.DuyuruBaslik 
AND TARGET.DuyuruIcerik  = SOURCE.DuyuruIcerik 
WHEN MATCHED
THEN UPDATE TARGET.SiteID  = SOURCE.fakulteID, TARGET.Dil  = SOURCE.dil, TARGET.DuyuruBaslik  = SOURCE.DuyuruBaslik, TARGET.DuyuruIcerik  = SOURCE.DuyuruIcerik -- Add Other Columns
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN INSERT(TARGET.SiteID, TARGET.Dil, TARGET.DuyuruBaslik, TARGET.DuyuruIcerik) VALUES(SOURCE.fakulteID, SOURCE.dil, SOURCE.DuyuruBaslik, SOURCE.DuyuruIcerik) -- Add Other Columns
```

If you want to keep your mismatched IDs' same in SOURCE as TARGET table then follow this;

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].A.[tblDuyuyular] ON;
GO

MERGE [dbo].A.[tblDuyuyular] AS TARGET
USING [dbo].B.[tblDuyuyular] AS SOURCE
ON TARGET.ID = SOURCE.ID 
AND TARGET.SiteID  = SOURCE.fakulteID 
AND TARGET.Dil  = SOURCE.dil
AND TARGET.DuyuruBaslik  = SOURCE.DuyuruBaslik 
AND TARGET.DuyuruIcerik  = SOURCE.DuyuruIcerik 
WHEN MATCHED
THEN UPDATE TARGET.SiteID  = SOURCE.fakulteID, TARGET.Dil  = SOURCE.dil, TARGET.DuyuruBaslik  = SOURCE.DuyuruBaslik, TARGET.DuyuruIcerik  = SOURCE.DuyuruIcerik -- Add Other Columns
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN INSERT(TARGET.ID, TARGET.SiteID, TARGET.Dil, TARGET.DuyuruBaslik, TARGET.DuyuruIcerik) VALUES(SOURCE.ID, SOURCE.fakulteID, SOURCE.dil, SOURCE.DuyuruBaslik, SOURCE.DuyuruIcerik); -- Add Other Columns

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].A.[tblDuyuyular] OFF;
GO
```

For any condition change the second line as follows

```
USING 
(
SELECT * FROM [dbo].B.[tblDuyuyular] WHERE 'YOUR CONDITION' = 'YOUR CONDITION'
)
AS SOURCE
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. 
How can i fix auto increment field problem. Here is some ID number : 27019
27026
27034
34275
34737
34770
34780
34796.
I'm using sql server 2008 r2.

Comment: For insertion auto identity column will be created automatically with incremental 1 against max value. You have no need to provide values. If you want to insert ID in SOURCE same as TARGET those are not matched I don't think that is possible.

Comment: One way you may achieve this. Disable Identity insert to SOURCE table and then insert with ID value. After Merge you may enable identity insert to SOURE table again.

Comment: Worked!, Thanks.

Can i add a where clause to this code?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the Merge statement

```
MERGE dbo.A.tblDuyurular as target
using dbo.B.tblDuyurular as source ON 
  ON  target.ID = source.ID,
  and target.SiteID = source.fakulteID,
  and target.Dil = source.dil,
  and target.DuyuruBaslik = source.DuyuruBaslik,
  and target.DuyuruIcerik = source.DuyuruIcerik,
WHEN matched THEN Update
  SET target.yourfields = source.yourfields
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN insert (yourfields) values(source.yourfields)
```